# Flexbox is not being wrapped on mobile

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox for a 3 column layout. The columns are wrapping when I use my browser and condense it down, but when I open the site on my mobile, it is showing as 3 columns and is twice as wide as the rest of the site.

I don't know why. I have tried searching this specific question but couldn't find it.

```css
.flex-container3 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 30px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-box11,
.flex-box12,
.flex-box13 {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px 30px 100px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container3">
  <div class="flex-box11">
    <h3></h3>
    <p> more content</p>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-box12">
    <h3></h3>
    <p> more content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-box13">
    <h3></h3>
    <p> more content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `meta` viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yea I am. I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Anyone else know??

Comment: Could you paste some screenshots?